# Get All MemoryCache Keys in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

As you know they removed EntriesCollection in dotnet 7 ...

source : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63731

possible let me know how can I access all "MemoryCache" Keys ?

earlier I used something like that to get all keys

```
var collection = PropertyHelper.GetPrivatePropertyValue<ICollection>(MemoryCache, "EntriesCollection");
```

now it not working

I really don't know what to do ..

Comment: OUt of curiosity why would you need that?

Answer (score 4):

While I highly recommend to avoid doing this (because it's internal implementation detail, you should look into creating custom `IMemoryCache` implementation, for example by wrapping the existing one, and monitoring
addition/removal/expiration), from the pure technical standpoint of view in the current .NET 7 implementation entries are stored in [`_coherentState`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1cd8c2ecc110e0f42e9225af748e78c19a00c3aa/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L30) which is of type [`CoherentState`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1cd8c2ecc110e0f42e9225af748e78c19a00c3aa/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L641), so you can try accessing it (though note that it can be not thread safe in theory):

```cs
var memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
memoryCache.GetOrCreate("test", entry => 1);
var fieldInfo = typeof(MemoryCache).GetField("_coherentState", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var propertyInfo = fieldInfo.FieldType.GetProperty("EntriesCollection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(memoryCache);
var dict = propertyInfo.GetValue(value);
var cacheEntries = dict as IDictionary;
var cacheEntry = cacheEntries["test"] as ICacheEntry;
```

Answer (score 4):

I use for delete. it works on .Net 7

```
 private IMemoryCache _cache;



     var fieldInfo = typeof(MemoryCache).GetField("_coherentState", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
     var propertyInfo = fieldInfo.FieldType.GetProperty("EntriesCollection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
     var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(_cache);
     var dict = propertyInfo.GetValue(value) as dynamic;

    
     List<ICacheEntry> cacheCollectionValues = new List<ICacheEntry>();

     foreach (var cacheItem in dict)
     {
         ICacheEntry cacheItemValue = cacheItem.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(cacheItem, null);
         cacheCollectionValues.Add(cacheItemValue);
     }

     var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     var keysToRemove = cacheCollectionValues.Where(d => regex.IsMatch(d.Key.ToString())).Select(d => d.Key).ToList();

     foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
     {
         _cache.Remove(key);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**